# Is there an R Markdown equivalent to \Sexpr{} in Sweave?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

Using R Markdown in knitr is there an equivalent to `\Sexpr{}` in Sweave?

Answer (score 53):

Yes.  You can use

```
`r your_expression_here`
```

So something like

```
2+2 is: `r 2+2`
```

Should produce:

```
2+2 is: 4
```

I initially found it a little difficult trying to figure out what the different syntax was for each of the different styles you could use in knitr (html, markdown, sweave, ...) and resorted to looking at Yihui's [minimal examples](http://yihui.name/knitr/demos) (which do a good job) but if you can read regular expressions you can view the [default pattern definitions](http://yihui.name/knitr/patterns).  You even have the option of defining your own syntax if you want.

Comment: It's advertised that you can change the default pattern, but if you try, you will be asked by Yihui why you want to do it. Strange, after so many other things were changed, and for good reasons. https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/226

Comment: I thought no one could read regular expressions.  Aren't they a write-once non-language? :-)

Comment: Initially to set up the parsing sure it takes more work but I guess it could save some typing in the long run if you write a lot of inline stuff.  Plus I know I've thought about messing around and changing some of those.  Why?  Because you gave us the option to do that :p

Comment: @Dason haha, yes, you can mess with many things in knitr, and if you go away from the default settings, you just need to be aware of reproducibility for other people (need to give them more instructions on how to compile the document)

Answer (score 23):

By default inline R code in R Markdown will be formatted as code. If you just want output to appear `asis` then inclose the R command in `I(...)`. Enclosing output with `I(...)` matches the behaviour of `Sexpr`. This distinction is sometimes important. For more information, see this comment by  [Yihui Xie](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/244#issuecomment-5833603). The following table shows the different output from R Markdown to Markdown to HTML.

```
R Markdown        `r 2 + 2`               `r I(2+2)`
Markdown              `4`                     4
HTML             <code>4</code>               4
```

Comment: You just pre-empted by question :)