# Use variable in Rmarkdown text

Tags: r, yaml, markdown, r-markdown

I am creating an Rmarkdown document.

My code chunk checks for the number of columns/rows in the dataset and saves the information in a variable.

```
{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
df_dimenzions <- dim(demo)
```

I want to use the data/information stored in the variable in the **rmarkdown text**.

> For example... outside of the code chunk, to write plain text such as:
>   The number of columns is {{df_dimensions[1]}} and the number of rows
>   is {{df_dimension[2]}}

Is something like this possible in rmarkdown? Again, I'm asking for data that is processed within the rmarkdown, not stored outside of the document?

Also, I am aware that I can paste a concatinated string with the code-chunk. That is not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Related/possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902504/r-markdown-accessing-variable-from-code-chunk-variable-scope ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629416/is-there-an-r-markdown-equivalent-to-sexpr-in-sweave

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `` `r df_dimensions[1]` ``  in the main text.

Comment: can a variable be printed on top of a document i.e. before it is created later in the document ?