# How to format R Markdown variable name within regular text?

Tags: r, formatting, r-markdown

How can I format my variable names like "name" in the image below? I've tried inline r code and a bunch of the formatting tips on the R markdown cheat sheet, but can't imitate it.

I apologize for the simple question. I spent a bunch of time looking for the answer but can't seem to get the right keywords or something. I also see this formatting a bunch in my homework assignments and on online R resources, so it's burning me up inside not even knowing how to look it up.

[image: Example of desired format]

I've tried a bunch of formats from these websites: [RMarkdown Cheat Sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf), [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898893/use-variable-in-rmarkdown-text?newreg=69a54076f51e4af18c50afc469b6eabd), and many other SO pages. Also looked on various websites that popped up when looking up "how to format variables in R markdown inline/within text" or similar variations. Have a strong feeling I'm going to pinch myself when I get the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for

```markdown
- `name`: The class title
```

Which renders as

- `name`: The class title