# Refer variable to LATEX function

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

Hi I am writing an R Markdown document in which there is a Latex function. I would like to refer the variable in the LATEX to the variable in the R code so that it automatically update the LATEX if the R code generates a new results for the variable.

---

Rcode:

```
var = rnorm(1,0)
```

Latex part:

```
$$ f(x) = beta_{0}*var $$
```

---

I have already looked these links but they doesn't work for me. 
https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rmd;
[Is there an R Markdown equivalent to \Sexpr{} in Sweave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629416/is-there-an-r-markdown-equivalent-to-sexpr-in-sweave); https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362119/passing-variable-from-r-to-latex

Comment: What did you try after reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629416/is-there-an-r-markdown-equivalent-to-sexpr-in-sweave?

Answer (score 2):

You can do

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
var <- rnorm(1)
cat(sprintf("$$f(x) = \\beta_0*%s$$", var))
```
````

Comment: Thank you. There is still a little problem... After the "var" I need to complete the latex function... In fact I need to write a linear regression f(x) = beta_{0} + var * beta{1} + var2 * beta{2} + e.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question has been answered in the post [Is there an R Markdown equivalent to \Sexpr{} in Sweave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629416/is-there-an-r-markdown-equivalent-to-sexpr-in-sweave) You can use inline R expressions `` `r ` ``, e.g.

```latex
$$f(x) = \beta_{0} + `r var` * \beta_{1} + `r var2` * \beta_{2} + e$$
```

where `var` and `var2`, etc. are your variables in R.

Comment: I am trying this code: $$y = `r beta0` + `r beta0` * x + e$$ where obviously beta0 = 0.05 has been previously defined. However, it seems that latex doesn't recognise it and I get this output: y = 'rbeta0'+'rbeta0'*x + e instead of a correct version that should be: y = 0.05 + 0.05*x